# How to create space below HTML gadget/widget so it is between the header and the main blog posts?

Tags: html, widget, slider, blogger, cincopa

I used Cincopa to create a full-screen width image slider for my blogger. I used this code:

```
    #HTML4 {
     position: relative;
    top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;


}
```

And so it ended up looking like this: 
[image: image of their issue #1]

However, if you pay close attention, there are still white margins at the sides. Meaning it is not a real full screen header. Since I know fixed positions are not feasible, and I want to be able to scroll past the widget, I used an absolute position.

```
 #HTML4 {
 position: absolute;
top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;


}
```

However, it ended up looking like this—going behind my main blog and sidebar.

[image: image of their issue #2]

So I changed the Z-index, and still, it overlaps my main posts. This time, however, it's in front/on top of my main posts, instead of behind.

Everything about the slider is perfect already—it's interactive, it's full-screen, etc. However, no matter how much I try to alter the top and bottom of the new code, it won't budge upwards. I want the slider to be in between my header and my side bar + main blog post body, without moving my main blog post body and side bar all the way down. Yes, I know I should make the position relative for this to happen, but as you can see, when I make the position relative, the widget for the slider does not become full-screen. It is only when the position is set to absolute that it becomes full-screen—however, as an absolute position, it overlaps the main posts and sidebar of my blog, instead of having enough space to, like, push the main posts and sidebar down like it does when the position is set to relative.

How can I remedy this? My goal is to create a full-screen image slider, meaning HTML4 should not have any side margins, but it should also be positioned relatively so you can scroll past it, etc.

Thank you if ever!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more code to the question?

By the way try

```
position:relative;
```

in your sidebar..

But would appreciate if you add more code to visualize.